# release NSKeyedUnarchiver cause crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, memory-management

```
-(id)func
{
        NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unachiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    id object = [unachiver decodeObjectForKey:key];
    [unachiver finishDecoding];
        [unachiver release];
        [data release];
    return object;
}
```

when call this method, for example:

```
id anotherObject = [self func];
```

then when I send a message to anotherObject, it will cause a crash, I know it's a dangle pointer, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: do you mean [anotherObject func] by  "when I send a message to anotherObject"? where have you written your method? does the crash report unknown selector?

Comment: OK,let me make it simple, I found that the crush happens when program goes to [unarchiver release];

Comment: please wait for me to get this problem clear, I am a little messed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decodeObjectForKey:` is returning an autoreleased object. By the time you are sending a message to `anotherObject`, it has been dealloc'd. To stop this, you need to make sure to `retain` the object when you take ownership of it:

```
id anotherObject = [[self func] retain];
```

When you are finished with the object you should call `release` to ensure that it gets deallocated.